# How do I SUM a UNION ALL Subquery in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, union, union-all

For the code below, I'm getting the following error message from Oracle:

> "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected".

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.code,
    SUM(t1.productCount)
FROM
    (SELECT
        id1,
        code1,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(product)) as productCount1
    FROM
        table1
    GROUP BY
        id1,
        code1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        id2,
        code2,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(product2)) as productCount2
    FROM
        table2
    GROUP BY
        id2,
        code2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        id3,
        code3,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(product3)) as productCount3
    FROM
        table3
    GROUP BY
        id3,
        code3) t1
GROUP BY
    t1.id,
    t1.code
```

Any advice?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. `distinct(product3)` is absolutely identical to `distinct product3`

Comment: One error I can see: you derived table (the union all) does not have a column `productCount`. The names of the columns of a union is (only) determined by the first query, so you have the columns `id1`, `code1` and `productCount1` available in the outer query. But that should actually give a different error.

Comment: I think your outer query has columns `id` and `code` and your inner union query produces columns with names `name1` and `code1` based on the first query in the union. This might be the issue.. you could try renaming the first inner query columns to `id` and `code` and re-run and see..

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the code you are really running; has it been modified to hide your real names so much that you've lost whatever is causing the problem? Can you make sure your question contains code that does actually cause that if you run it exactly as shown?

Comment: Are you running it in a tool way blank lines are not allowed within a query? In which case the error message would be for just part of your posted query SQL*Plus was a bit famous for that.

Comment: Running what's shown in SQL\*Plus with sqlblanklines off would get ORA-00933 though; and any further blank lines after the final select keyword would give other errors. The real code may still have that issue; or there may be further code in a script that is actually the only thing being executed.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    id,code,SUM(productCount1)

FROM
    (SELECT
        id1,
        code1,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(product)) as productCount1
    FROM
        table1
    GROUP BY
        id1,
        code1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    id2,
    code2,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(product2)) as productCount1
FROM
    table2
GROUP BY
    id2,
    code2

UNION ALL

SELECT
    id3,
    code3,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(product3)) as productCount1
FROM
    table3
GROUP BY
    id3,
    code3)
GROUP BY
    id,code
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this code.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(
  ID1      NUMBER,
  CODE1    NUMBER,
  PRODUCT  NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE2
(
  ID2       NUMBER,
  CODE2     NUMBER,
  PRODUCT2  NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE3
(
  ID3       NUMBER,
  CODE3     NUMBER,
  PRODUCT3  NUMBER
);

    SELECT
        t1.id,
        t1.code,
        SUM(t1.productCount)
    FROM
        (SELECT id1 as id,
        code1 as code,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(product)) as productCount
        FROM   table1
        GROUP BY  id1,  code1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id2 as id,
        code2 as code,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(product2)) as productCount
        FROM  table2
        GROUP BY id2,  code2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id3 as id,
        code3 as code,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(product3)) as productCount
        FROM  table3
        GROUP BY  id3, code3
        ) t1
    GROUP BY  t1.id,t1.code
```

I have created 3 tables for testing.
This code run without any error. Just follow the column alias in inner query and the column name of outer query will be same.

Comment: Worked for me with a little personalization.

Answer (score 0):

The query in the question would not produce the stated error and the following simply corrects for the column aliases and for use of distinct.

```
SELECT
      t1.idx
    , t1.codex
    , SUM(t1.productCount)
FROM (
      SELECT
            id1 AS idx
          , code1 AS codex
          , COUNT(DISTINCT product) AS productCount
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY
            id1
          , code1
      UNION ALL
            SELECT
                  id2
                , code2
                , COUNT(DISTINCT product2)
            FROM table2
            GROUP BY
                  id2
                , code2
      UNION ALL
            SELECT
                  id3
                , code3
                , COUNT(DISTINCT product3)
            FROM table3
            GROUP BY
                  id3
                , code3
      ) t1
GROUP BY
      t1.idx
    , t1.codex
```